# Highlighting parts of nodes in forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

In my forest (see code)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    folder,
    grow'=0,
    fit=band,
  }
[root
    [2020-01-01 10:05 part one part two] 
    [2020-01-01 10:10 part one part two] 
    [2020-01-01 10:10 part one part two] 
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I would like to highlight certain parts of each node (which is very tabular):

[image]

I thought it is a good idea to use TikZ one-line matrices for that, like:

```
[<no idea>, tikz={\node[matrix, matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&] (thematrix){
2020-01-01 10:05 \& Participant 1 \& created \\);]
% do the highlighting
```

But I am stuck: The matrix is placed at the top of the tree (and I don't know how to replace the node as a matrix). Maybe my approach is simply wrong. What are your ideas?

Update: Unfortunately, the [proposed solution by Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655715/51776) doesn't work for more complex trees:

```
[root
    [a
        [2020-01-01 10:05 {\subnode[inner sep=1pt]{one}{part one}} part two] 
        [2020-01-01 10:10 part one part two] 
        [2020-01-01 10:10 part one part two, name=two] 
    ]
    [
        b 
        [...]
    ]
]
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Whatever you use with the `tikz` key, is just executed at the end where you could reference any point or named node of the tree. Forest doesn't add nodes directly to the picture but first creates the node virtually and measures it so that it can calculate precisely where it should be. A matrix of nodes is – on the PGF/TikZ level – a special node with nodes. I suspect it's not easy to switch this off when inside the matrix. I would've gone for `[2020-01-01 10:10 \& part one \& part two \\, node options={matrix, matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&}] ` but this just creates an empty node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility using `tikzmark`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest, tikz}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    folder,
    grow'=0,
    fit=band,
  }
[root
    [2020-01-01 10:05 \tikzmark{A}part one part two] 
    [2020-01-01 10:10 part one part two] 
    [2020-01-01 10:10 part one\tikzmark{B} part two, draw=green, thick] 
]
\end{forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[draw, red, thick] ([shift={(-.1,.3)}]{pic cs:A}) rectangle ([shift={(.1,-.2)}]{pic cs:B});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a possible solution with `subnode` from `tikzmark` library and `forest` own nodes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    folder,
    grow'=0,
    fit=band,
  }
[root
    [2020-01-01 10:05 {\subnode[inner sep=1pt]{one}{part one}} part two] 
    [2020-01-01 10:10 part one part two] 
    [2020-01-01 10:10 part one part two, draw=green, name=two] 
]
\end{forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red] (one.north west) rectangle (one.east|-two.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant and exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Argh sorry I doesn't work as intended: if the "table" is not in root level, it doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelDorner Complete your question with a M(not)WE showing the problem.

Comment: Of course! Done. :)

Answer (score 0):

A small variation of the @Sandy G answer: with use of the Ti*k*Z library `fit`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, 
                tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    folder,
    grow'=0,
    fit=band,
  }
[root
    [2020-01-01 10:05 \tikzmark{A}part one part two]
    [2020-01-01 10:10 part one part two]
    [2020-01-01 10:10 part one\tikzmark{B} part two, draw=green, thick]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
FIT/.style = {draw=blue, thick, inner xsep=1pt,
              inner ysep=1.6ex, yshift=0.4ex, fit=#1}
                    ]
\node[FIT=(pic cs:A) (pic cs:B)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]